# Load Content If IE or Not IE

Tags: html, html5-video

While designing my site i am attempting to use the HTML5 video tag.  The video works using HTML5 in most browsers, and if it doesn't then it uses the flash fallback that i have included in the code.  The main code is as follows:

```
<video controls autoplay preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
<source src="http://incisionindustries.com/clients/luminal/gictg/wp-content/themes/Karma/images/_global/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://incisionindustries.com/clients/luminal/gictg/wp-content/themes/Karma/images/_global/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fincisionindustries.com%2Fclients%2Fluminal%2Fgictg%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2FKarma%2Fimages%2F_global%2Fvideo.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
</object>
</video>
```

Now the only browser that this still does not work on is IE9.  IE9 sees the HTML5 video command and loads the player for a split second but never loads the video.  So what i tried to do was to set it up as follows:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fincisionindustries.com%2Fclients%2Fluminal%2Fgictg%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2FKarma%2Fimages%2F_global%2Fvideo.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
</object>
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
<video controls autoplay preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
<source src="http://incisionindustries.com/clients/luminal/gictg/wp-content/themes/Karma/images/_global/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://incisionindustries.com/clients/luminal/gictg/wp-content/themes/Karma/images/_global/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fincisionindustries.com%2Fclients%2Fluminal%2Fgictg%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2FKarma%2Fimages%2F_global%2Fvideo.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
</object>
</video>
<![endif]>
```

However with this code loaded all the other browsers work again with the exception of IE9.  It is not picking up the if IE tag and it is just going straight to the HTML 5 page which doesn't load.

Really what i am trying to do is say if it is ANY version of IE to use the flash based player and if it is anything else use the HTML5 with the flash fallback. If anyone could give some inside on how to make this work or a more elegant solution it would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
// here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like **[modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)** to check for your browsers features (instead of browser sniffing and making assumptions - they might be wrong or change). Depending on the client's capabilities you can then start serving the right content.

Another approach (if it's plain video only and you don't need any other feature detections) would be using something like shown at **[Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#video-code)**.

This is the code they are proposing to embed video for *everybody*:

```
<!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise -->
<!-- warning: playback does not work on iOS3 if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4.0 -->
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
    <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
        <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
        <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
        <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
<!-- you *must* offer a download link as they may be able to play the file locally. customise this bit all you want -->
<p> <strong>Download Video:</strong>
    Closed Format:  <a href="__VIDEO__.MP4">"MP4"</a>
    Open Format:    <a href="__VIDEO__.OGV">"Ogg"</a>
</p>
```